# Adding external CSS (FontAwesome) to an SPFx webpart on SPO?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, font-awesome

I use the code below to try to put FontAwesome in my web part.

It creates the tag on the page but it doesn't display anything.
When I view source on the page I don't see a reference to the CSS file.

Any ideas?

```
export default class FancyTextWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IFancyTextWebPartProps> {


  // public constructor(context: IWebPartContext) {
  //   super(context);
  
  //   ModuleLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');
  // }

  constructor() {
    super();
    
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');
  }

  public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
        <div>
          <i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i>
          <div class="${ styles.customWebPart }">
          <p> ${this.generatePage()}</p>
          </div>
        </div>`;
  }
```

Comment: Even trying this doesn't add the css when I view source ... protected onInit(): Promise<void> {

    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    return super.onInit();
    
  }

Comment: Check the sample code given [here](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/b139ba199cb57363a88f070dd9814e5af4fc3cbd/samples/js-advanced-commenting/src/webparts/pageComments/PageCommentsWebPart.ts). let me know if it helps/works.

Comment: Thanks @GaneshSanap that seems to load now but it's tiny. Is there a way to change the icons size? thanks for the help.

Comment: Check my answer given below.

Comment: This doesnt increase the size at all ... <i class="fas fa-camera fa-10x">

Comment: Which version of fontAwesome css are you using? You can see more examples [here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/examples/). **If you change the font-size of the icon's container, the icon gets bigger.**

Comment: this.domElement.innerHTML = `
        <div>
        <i class="fas fa-camera fa-10x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-camera fa-10x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
          <div class="${ styles.customWebPart }">
          <p> ${this.generatePage()}</p>
          </div>
        </div>`;

Comment: This renders a square (looks like a default non-loading icon), an x with a circle in it, another square and an x with a circle in it. They're all tiny though. Im using ... https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Try using: **this.domElement.innerHTML = ` <div style="font-size: 30px"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div> `**. You can change the font-size of parent element as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load & use `FontAwesome` CSS in your SPFx web part like this:

```
public constructor() {
    super();
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
}

this.domElement.innerHTML = `<div class="${styles.errorMessage}"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;${strings.NoAttachmentRepoMsg}</div>`;
```

**Source**: [PageCommentsWebPart.ts](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/b139ba199cb57363a88f070dd9814e5af4fc3cbd/samples/js-advanced-commenting/src/webparts/pageComments/PageCommentsWebPart.ts)

---

**Changing icon size**:

Icons inherit the `font-size` of their parent container which allow them to match any text you might use with them. With the following classes, we can increase or decrease the size of icons relative to that inherited `font-size`:

```
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-xs"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-sm"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-lg"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-2x"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-3x"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-5x"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-7x"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-10x"></i>
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Source**: [Sizing Icons](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons)

Comment: Thanks so much Ganesh